# Regex - Match @function[args1|args2]

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an issue to match a certain pattern in Regex

- Case 1 : @Function[]
- Case 2 : @Function[args1|args2]
- Case 3 : @Function

I want this result

- Case 1 : 1-Function 2-
- Case 2 : 1-Function 2-args1|args2
- Case 3 : 1-Function 2-

I match the two first pattern with `\@(.?*)\[(.?*)\]` but not the third.

Thank you for your time.
Aubin

Comment: how come your pattern or the answer didn't use the word `Function` in it... can it be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\@([^[\]]+)(?:\[(.*?)\])?
```

(btw you made a mistake while writing your regex here I guess, as you wrote: `.?*`)

**Edit:** forgot the second capturing group.

**Edit2:** as for the reason the previous didn't work, the lazy operator of the first group made sure to get the smallest match. So the second part was tested while the first matched "" (nothing), and was a success too as it has a ? operator.

Comment: @AubinLorieux Sorry it was obviously wrong yes :) corrected and working.